# Alternative to JqueryUI?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, styling, vaadin

Need alternative to JqueryUI mostly for styling input, select and other such stuff. 
I saw ninjaUI and Vaadin. Vaadin is really sexy, i wonder if there are any alike that are as good as mentioned ?

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  I myself have a nice collection of controls and have wondered whether to make a bootstrap myself or to extend one.  Twitter bootstrap is crap, so I will definitely be looking into these.

Comment: I wrote to the devs of ninjaUI with a bucket list of many controls.  They wrote back to say that over this year they will be implemented.  This means that ninjaUI > twitter bootstrap and Vaadin.  Personally, I can't wait.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to just style stuff you might as well use something like bootstrap by Twitter: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/ . Css will render faster than javascript mostly.

Comment: Twitter bootstrap is kinda crap really.  It's poor compared to other stuff that is out there and you can certainly make something much better, it's not really that hard.

Answer (score 1):

There's [KendoUI](http://www.kendoui.com/), but it's not open source.  You have to pay when you use it commercially.

Comment: crapp it is expensive, atm i need more css style stuff, but hey i am aware that i will need some of that cool stuff in js in near future, still wondering best solution for me :(

Comment: I'm in the same boat as you.  I've got lots of standalone plugins that are the same functionality.  But not exactly a bootstrap/library that makes it easy to implement functionality as quickly as say ninjaui.